# What is the proper order for adding transitions in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Struggling to add css opacity transition with js. When clicking on a tab, the js loop hides all content and only shows the content with the corresponding id. Im trying to get the loop to add the transition as well. The tabcontent class is the CSS in question.

```
        <li>
          <a style="left: 9.6%" href="javascript:switchTab('tb_1', 'content_1', 'icon_1');" id="tb_1" class="tabmenu active">FIT GUIDE<span class='mobileshow' id='icon_1'>-<span></a>
          <section id="content_1" class="tabcontent">
            <p class='lorem'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui</p>
          </section>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a style="left: 39%;" href="javascript:switchTab('tb_2', 'content_2', 'icon_2');" id="tb_2" class="tabmenu">CARE <span class='mobileshow' id='icon_2'>+</span></a>
          <section id="content_2" class="tabcontent" style="display:none; opacity: 0;">
            <p class='lorem'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui</p>
          </section>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a style="left: 60.6%" href="javascript:switchTab('tb_3', 'content_3', 'icon_3');" id="tb_3" class="tabmenu">MATERIALS <span class='mobileshow' id='icon_3'>+</span></a>
          <section id="content_3" class="tabcontent" style="display:none; opacity: 0;">
            <div class='materials-content'>
              <ul class='materials-stats'>
                <li class='material-item'>50%<span class='subtext'>cashmere</span></li>
                <li class='material-item'>46%<span class='subtext right'>wool</span></li>
                <li class='material-item'>4%<span class='subtext'>modal</span></li>
              </ul>
              <div class='border-bot'></div>
              <p class='lorem'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui</p>
            </div>
          </section>
        </li>
      </ul>

function switchTab(tab_id, tab_content, icon_id) {
    // select tab content
    let content = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      // hide tab content
      content[i].style.opacity = '0';
      content[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    //document.getElementById(tab_content).style.display = 'block';
    //document.getElementById(tab_content).classList.add("showme");
    document.getElementById(tab_content).style.cssText = "opacity: 1; display: block;"
} 
  .tabcontent {
    max-width: 750px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    position:  relative;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to animate `opacity` and `display` at the same time. You would probably want to set `display: block` first, and then change the `opacity`. Or the other way around if you want to hide the block.

I think you might want to have a look at `@keyframes`. Here's a link to documentation about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

It will look something like this:

```
@keyframes yourAnimation {
  from {
    transform: opacity(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: opacity(1);
  }
}
```

Have a class named `animation` and apply the keyframes to that. Then add the class to the HTMLElement you want to be animated using JS. This will cause the CSS animation to occur.

CSS for this part will be looking something like this:

```
.animation {
    animation: yourAnimation;
}
```

It seems like the JS part you can manage, but if you need more help let me know!